# High frequency Driver circuit

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm looking for a 2Mhz 24v 100mA Driver circuit for my Piezo transducer. I am not sure that MOSFET could handle that, if it could there are not much design ideas for the same on internet. And there are high frequency LED driver ICs like LT3598, but I'm not sure about those too. Somebody please help me with this.

Comment: For piezo you want an h-bridge really.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but this is for the application of Ultrasonic Humidifier. I wrote program for generating a PWM of 1,7MHz, it is a single polarity waveform, and the Piezo transducer also a single polarity device. So an H bridge is too much and most of the components will not be doing anything at all the time.

Comment: Please provide a link to the actual device you are using. Piezo transducers are a capacitive device, and with nothing to allow the capacitance to empty after each charge cycle you will have very poor results. For low frequency (audio) a simple resistor can be used. For high frequency you want something faster at discharging like an h-bridge. If your device has its own circuitry in it then that really changes the whole thing.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32854394686.html     here you can find the actual device